# Understanding how content is served from the database to frontend web pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

I want to understand on a conceptual level how information travels from the Database(Microsoft SQL) to the Frontend with C# & ASP.Net . I have not had much luck finding examples or diagrams which address this concept in a clear way. One example could be sending the string "Hello I am a string stored in the database & now I appear on this front end web page", It does not have to be specific to these languages, although if it is that would be great. Ultimately, I want to understand what are the components involved and how do they communicate information back and forth.Any articles,videos or diagrams that you feel of importance are also highly valued, thank you for your time.

Comment: I don't think this question is very suitable for SO.

Comment: I don't disagree as it maybe to large a subject to address, which is why I am also open to other resources such as articles, videos or diagrams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a diagram. I hope it helps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An overview could be like:

- User sends request to web server through client i.e. browser
- Web server queries database
- Get query results
- Generates HTML (if results found)
- Send back to the browser
- Browser displays on the screen

Every step has details but it is an overview, hope makes some sense.

Comment: I was able to find content which described this on to a greater degree here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cb8MkRr9gu0  which was very beneficial as well, thank you to everyone who commented it helped me considerably as I can now look into each compontent. Stack Overflow perhaps this question is to broad to be addressed here but these are issues which any programmer will encounter at some point in their development so deal with it.

Comment: @DSchreiter, thank for sharing a good youtube link, glad if my answer helped you. vote up if this is the case. Thanks